# How to set absolute path for img attribute in html

Tags: html, reactjs, django, image, src

sorry for this dummy question but i am having a trouble in my django and react app.
i have an endpoint which serves the image name but the image is saved in my local directory and in my react app i just want to append the file name like this
function Condition(props) {
let src = `C:/Users/25191/Desktop/python_projects/doctorsolve/Drsove/media/media/images/HealthCondition/${props.meddata.image}`

```
return (
    <>
        <div className="item">
            <a href="#">
                <img src={src} alt="medicine item image" />
                <div className="desc">
                    <p className="medicinename">{props.meddata.title}</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to refer to a local file, then use the file URI:

```
file:///C:/Users/25191/Desktop/python_projects/doctorsolve/Drsove/media/media/images/HealthCondition/${props.meddata.image}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
 <img src="" alt="description">
```